# Java program won't compile: missing return statement

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm trying to learn java and this my first time asking a question here.
My program won't compile because of a missing return statement in this method, but I can't seem to find where I went wrong...

```
static double[][] matrixPow(double[][] matrixA, int e) {

    if (e == 0) {
        double [][] I = new double[matrixA[0].length][matrixA.length];
        for (int k = 0; k < matrixA.length; k++) {
            I[k][k] = 1;
        }
        return I;
    } else if ((e % 2) == 0) {
        return matrixPow( matrixMult(matrixA, matrixA), e/2);
    } else if ((e % 2) == 1) {
        return matrixMult(matrixA, matrixPow(matrixA, (e - 1)));
    }
}
```

This method is supposed to calculate a matrix to the power of an integer e.

Comment: This method should always return a value

Comment: You need a return statement after the final else-if even if it's impossible to reach, per the the Java Spec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `else if` statement and there is no return statement if all of your statement fails. You need to return something at the end of the function, or in a `else` block.

```
static double[][] matrixPow(double[][] matrixA, int e) {

 //Einheitsmatrix
 if (e == 0) {
  double[][] I = new double[matrixA[0].length][matrixA.length];
  for (int k = 0; k < matrixA.length; k++) {
   I[k][k] = 1;
  }
  return I;
 }
 //Der eine Kram
 else if ((e % 2) == 0) {
  return matrixPow(matrixMult(matrixA, matrixA), e / 2);
 }
 //der andere Kram
 else if ((e % 2) == 1) {
  return matrixMult(matrixA, matrixPow(matrixA, (e - 1)));
 }
 // we return null in case every other cases fails.
 return null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message clearly states, there is at least one branch that has no return statement. In this case it's the one where neither the if nor any of the else-ifs triggers.

This case can't happen in real life, but the compiler doesn't know that and has no way of figuring out. Just convert the last else-if branch into an else and everything should be good.